# What's the purpose of setReportDelay for BluetoothLeScanner in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-5.0-lollipop, android-bluetooth, altbeacon

What's the purpose of [setReportDelay](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings.Builder.html#setReportDelay%28long%29) for BluetoothLeScanner in Android? I can't imagine why one would get reports with delay...

Answer (score 2):

From [Android Official Site](http://developer-android.ir/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings.Builder.html):

**setReportDelay()** takes `reportDelayMillis` parameter where `reportDelayMillis` is:

> Delay of report in milliseconds. Set to 0 to be notified of results
>   immediately. Values > 0 causes the scan results to be queued up and
>   delivered after the requested delay or when the internal buffers fill
>   up

coming to your question:

> What's the purpose of setReportDelay for BluetoothLeScanner in Android? I can't imagine why one would get reports with delay...|

As i understood the purpose of this is that sometimes when you scan for a very short period of time, not all the `devices/beacons` can be found, but on the second scan another one can be cought while scanning.

**Ex:** 
Suppose you have three `beacons` and you made two different scans for `1s`. On the first scan only single beacon is found, but on the second other beacons found too. Setting a delay will `queue` all of them and you will be able to show all of them. Otherwise sometimes single beacon, sometimes all of them and sometimes two of them will be shown.(This is related mostly with the `frequency` they transmit)

You can use also `Lists` for this purpose, so when a `beacon` is found you add them to the `list` and show them after some `delay`(using `Handler/Timer`). But this will require more work. So it is probably simplified with this function

Answer (score 2):

setReportDelay() > 0 causes the scanner to queue up results and then fire the onBatchScanResults() from ScanCallback rather than the normal onScanResult().

This is quite useful if you need to do a UI update every few seconds: rather than refreshing your UI every time an announcement packet arrives, you can simply delay the results. Also, you get a more complete result set.

Note that your device need to be able to support this. See

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#isOffloadedScanBatchingSupported()

Answer (score 0):

Different devices scan slightly differently. When scanning some will return the same found device multiple times per scan.

If you set a delay, Android will create a queue, and all duplicates are filtered out before that list of devices in the queue is returned.